# AngularJS : Custom directive scope not being initialized properly when used with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem with passing object information to my custom directive, which has an isolate scope. I have boiled my problem down to this simple plnkr to demonstrate the wall I am hitting:

http://plnkr.co/edit/oqRa5pU9kqvOLrMWQx1u

Am I just using ng-repeat and directives incorrectly? Again, my goal is to pass the object information from the ng-repeat loop into my directive which will have its own scope.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="i in items", my-directive="i">
        <span>{{$index}}</span>
        <p>{{item.name}}</p>
        <p>{{item.value}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
      {name: "Name #1", value: "Value #1"},
      {name: "Name #2", value: "Value #2"},
      {name: "Name #3", value: "Value #3"}
    ];
});

app.directive('myDirective', function($scope) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: { item: "=myDirective" },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

    }
  }
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues:

- remove `$scope` from directive function
- remove comma from HTML after `ng-repeat`

Provide element with new attribute, for example `value` but `my-directive="i"` will work as well.

**HTML**

```
 <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="i in items" my-directive value="i">
        <span>{{$index}}</span>
        <p>{{item.name}}</p>
        <p>{{item.value}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
      {name: "Name #1", value: "Value #1"},
      {name: "Name #2", value: "Value #2"},
      {name: "Name #3", value: "Value #3"}
    ];
});

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: { item: "=value" },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      console.log(scope.item);
    }
  }
});
```

Demo <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mBrWbK0n3IvmfMz1qwcg?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Do you know why it is necessary to have to create a new attribute and assign it to that? It would be neater if I could pass it directly to the name of the directive.