# Using ng-repeat with directive causes flaw in watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, carousel, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have made a new directive that is basically a new carousel that extends the angular UI carousel bootstrap. This new carousel will display multiple divs in one frame. My new directive accepts any data in an array and a custom html template for each data.

However, if I use my carousel with a directive, there is a weird behaviour that I am seeing with watch inside the directive. Everything works fine, but the watch inside my directive is always getting the same value for `newVal` and `oldVal`. What I mean is this, here's my carousel code:

```
<slide ng-repeat="frame in ctrl.frames">
     <div ng-repeat="divs in frame.divs">
       <custom-directive data="divs"></custom-directive>
     </div>
</slide>
```

and inside my `customDirective` controller, I watch the change of data like this:

```
$scope.$watch("ctrl.data", function(newVal, oldVal){
     if (newVal !== oldVal) {
         // data is updated, redraw the directive in my case
         // however newVal is always the same as oldVal
     }
})
```

newVal and oldVal is always the same.. I expected the initial state to be `oldVal = undefined` and `newVal` will be my new data. However, this is never the case. Data is passed as a two-way binding to carousel and to custom directive (using '=' operator inside the scope of each directive).

**Why is this happening?** I have investigated this for long and here's my findings:

1. If **I don't use** `ng-repeat` inside my carousel, this **will work**. `oldVal` will be `undefined` and `newVal` will be my data during the initial state. But why is ng-repeat causing this? I have read lots of article regarding **golden rule of prototypical inheritance**, that says **ng-repeat will create new childScope that hides/shadows the parent**, but that only happens to **primitive object** and I am passing an **array** to my data.

I need to use ng-repeat in my carousel directive.. so I need to know why ng-repeat is causing this.. any suggestions?

UPDATE:
Reproduced the problem in Plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mNN4UuDJZdZZWr52fYar). As you can see, oldValue is always the same as newValue (I expected the oldValue to be undefined in the beginning)

Comment: Are you sure this function is actually being called? Or is it just that it has never gotten into your `if (newVal !== oldVal)` code? (Outside of initially)

Comment: Also, it's a little unclear how the `ctrl.data` relates to the data in the `ng-repeat`s in the html. Where is `ctrl.data` used in the html exactly? This might help figure out any scope/structure issues

Comment: @brettvd yes this function is being called. I am sure because when I debug, watch is being called but newVal is always the same as oldVal

Comment: @brettvd so in my custom-directive, I pass in a "divs" to data. this data is binded to the custom directive controller to a ctrl.data...

Comment: Does this fire every time data changes just as you expect? Do the newVal/oldVal match the before or after data state? Have you tried replicating this in simpler code in like a Plunkr or JSFidde?

Comment: @brettvd updated the question with Plunkr example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register the `$watch` in your `link` function, Angular has already processed the bindings during the `preLink` phase, hence you will never see `undefined` the first time your watcher is executed (that initialiation call is the only moment on which oldVal and newVal are potentially the same. If the watcher was registered *before* the bindings resolution, the oldValue would be `undefined`)

If you *really* want to see it, you could override the `compile` phase and add a custom `preLink` method (the default `link` being the `postLink`).

But I really doubt that you want to do that. Why is it a problem to not have undefined the first time? You should try to explain the real problem you are facing.

Also, note that if `divs` that you pass to your directive is an array, you should use `scope.$watchColleciton` instead of `scope.$watch` in order to detect changes in the array elements instead of change of the whole array pointer.

Comment: the reason why I want to see undefined in oldValue is because inside my watch I have a `if (newVal !== oldVal)`. Since oldVal is the same with newVal during initialization, I never get my data to my directive... but I get what you mean though, I realize I should not rely on watch in the first place to initialize my data.

Comment: Indeed. Either remove that condition since the only time it is false is during the initialization, or typically do something like `if (newVal !== oldVal) { scope.init(); }` and then also call `scope.init()` outside of the watcher, with all the logic within that function.

Comment: Removing newVal !== oldVal will definitely work :) I realized that during init my data is not initialized yet, just like what this post is saying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465840/custom-directive-scope-not-being-initialized-properly-when-used-with-ng-repeat but maybe it's something else that's causing it. Anyways thanks very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you are having is just a misunderstanding of how `$watch` works.

`$watch` is *expected* to initialize with equal values. See the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope). Specifically:

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is
>   called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In
>   rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when
>   the result of watchExpression didn't change. To detect this scenario
>   within the listener fn, you can compare the newVal and oldVal. If
>   these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due
>   to initialization

So in other words, your check for if they are equal is so you *don't* detect the initial call

In your provided Plunker, if you need to do some initialization code, you can do two things:

1. You can check if they *are* equal in the `$watch` function, and if they are then that is the initial call with their initial values
2. Or, outside of that function in the `link` function, the values are their initial values there (since the `link` function is equivalent to `post-link`, which means `scope` values have already been linked) so you can put your code there

Forked your Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/u9xzOHQh1fGSziHEPlhr?p=preview). Notice I moved the `alert` outside of the `$watch`, and the value is still valid

**EDIT:**

The reason you see a difference when it is not in the `ng-repeat` and it is set up like your commented out code in the Plunkr is due to you adding data in a `$timeout`. When the page **initially** loads, below are what the two types render as:

1. `<a1 prop="data[0]"></a1>`

   - HTML looks as it was written. `data=[]`. directive element exists, calling `link` with `data[0]=undefined`. `$watch` called with `prop=undefined`
2. `<!-- ngRepeat: element in data track by $index -->`

   - HTML is simply a comment. waiting for `data` to be populated. No directive element exists, which means `link` is not called

When you add items to `data` **after** the timeout, they look like this:

1. `<a1 prop="data[0]"></a1>`

   - Same as above. `data[0]` is now defined so `prop` is defined
2. `<div ng-repeat="element in data track by $index" class="ng-scope">
      <a1 prop="element" class="ng-isolate-scope"></a1>
    </div>` (x3)

   - Page now has directive elements. calling `link` function on each with `data` now filled. `$watch` called with `prop` values linked

Comment: but shouldn't the watch get called the first time with `newVal = undefined` and `oldVal = undefined` as the initialization?

Comment: Not always. Like it says in the documentation: "After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher". When you are registering the `$watch` function in your directive, the values have already been linked. So the initial values are equal, as described, but happen to have a value. If it was always passing `undefined`, I would think the documentation would recommend to check for that instead of `if ( newValue !== oldValue )`

Comment: Edited to explain the `ng-repeat` difference you were seeing